# PostgreSQL not working on docker when volume is initialized

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using windows docker
my docker-compose file is as shown below:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-root}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      -  ./postgres-data:/var/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

When i build it i get following error log and container exits

```
Attaching to postgres_container
postgres_container | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres_container | This user must also own the server process.
postgres_container |
postgres_container | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres_container | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres_container | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres_container |
postgres_container | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres_container |
postgres_container | fixing permissions on existing directory /data/postgres ... ok
postgres_container | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres_container | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres_container | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres_container | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres_container | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres_container | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres_container | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgres_container | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgres_container | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres_container |
postgres_container |
postgres_container | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres_container |
postgres_container |     pg_ctl -D /data/postgres -l logfile start
postgres_container |
postgres_container | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres_container | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres_container | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres_container | waiting for server to start....2020-04-17 13:18:31.599 UTC [47] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:31.607 UTC [47] LOG:  could not bind Unix address "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432": Input/output error
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:31.607 UTC [47] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, remove socket file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" and retry.
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:31.607 UTC [47] WARNING:  could not create Unix-domain socket in directory "/var/run/postgresql"
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:31.607 UTC [47] FATAL:  could not create any Unix-domain sockets
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:31.610 UTC [47] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_container |  stopped waiting
postgres_container | pg_ctl: could not start server
postgres_container | Examine the log output.
postgres_container |
postgres_container | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_container |
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:32.246 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:32.246 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:32.246 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:32.255 UTC [1] LOG:  could not bind Unix address "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432": Input/output error
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:32.255 UTC [1] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, remove socket file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" and retry.
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:32.255 UTC [1] WARNING:  could not create Unix-domain socket in directory "/var/run/postgresql"
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:32.255 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not create any Unix-domain sockets
postgres_container | 2020-04-17 13:18:32.259 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_container exited with code 1
```

I checked 5432 port its open and no process is using it.

> when i remove volume from my docker-compose.yml file it works
>   perfectly

the volume i am using ./postgres-data is the local directory on my system i want to map it to the PostgreSQL container to restore database.

Comment: try  "./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data" as volume

Comment: You're hiding a bunch of system directories with the bind mount over all of `/var`; the standard `/var/run` directory won't exist in this setup, for example, which leads to your failure.

Comment: @TibebeselasieMehari I tried that it started working,but volume is not getting mapped i.e whenever i put backup file in my local dir its not available in container

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks changed the dir and its working

Answer (score 0):

You are using docker on Windows and mounting the directory where the socket will be created (`/var`) as volume but windows filesystem doesn't support unix sockets.

Change the configuration in order to:

- leave the unix socket (`/var/run/postgresql/...`) inside the docker without mounting as volume
- mount data directory as volume